# How to return table from PL/pgSQL function?

Tags: plpgsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function(user_id integer) 
     RETURNS TABLE(id integer, firstname character varying, lastname character varying) 
AS $$
DECLARE
    ids INTEGER[];
BEGIN
     ids := ARRAY[1,2];
     RETURN QUERY
         SELECT users.id, users.firstname, users.lastname
         FROM public.users
         WHERE users.id = ANY(ids);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

```
select * from my_function(1);
```

Comment: Showing your code is a good idea in general, but you should also write some text, what you are trying to achieve and what is not working. And format your code so that it shows as code, which greatly improves readability.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify as requested. The obvious problem: you are not using the input parameter in the function body.